# Different builds for web and mobile with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, mobile, web, build

I want to write an app with Meteor js that have 3 main modules, a web admin panel, a web app version and a mobile app version. I want to have the 3 apps in the same Meteor project ¿how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is create 3 separate projects and share server side code between them using symbolic links (`ln -s`). This solution is simple, but crude and may be hard to maintain.

So there is another way: split app into packages. It is more complicated, but easier to maintain. This way described [here](http://meteorpatterns.com/Sewdn/project-builds).